# ios & obj-c methods that do not need declaration in header

Tags: objective-c, ios, uipickerview

I was checking some video at Lynda.com about iphone development.

The guy was adding custom data to a picker, but to add the data he was not declaring the methods in the header file. He was checking which nethods he needed on the documentation and copying pasting those methods declarations in his controller class.

For exampe this method

```
-(int) numberOfComponentsInPickerView: (UIPickerView *) pickerView
```

Why doesn't we need to declare those methods on the header file?

If those methods pertain to the picker class, why do we declare them in the controller class instead of simply calling them in the picker IBOutlet instance?

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare in your header that you follow a certain protocol, you are essentially saying that you agree to implement the methods defined in the protocol.
I'll bet he added something like this to the header:

```
<UIPickerViewDataSource>
```

That means that he is implementing the UIPickerViewDataSource protocol.

So, by implementing the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol, you are implying those methods, therefore, they do not need to be prototyped.

Answer (score 1):

> If those methods pertain to the picker class, why do we declare them in the controller class instead of simply calling them in the picker IBOutlet instance?

The method you quoted does not belong to the `UIPickerView` class, but rather to the `UIPickerViewDataSource` protocol. Your controller acts as a "helper" for the picker, so the picker is calling your controller if it needs to figure out how many components it should display. You are usually not calling this method yourself.

As [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6514185/ios-obj-c-methods-that-do-not-need-declaration-in-header#answer-6514227) pointed out, by declaring that you implement the protocol, the methods of that protocol are implicitly declared. By adding `<UIPickerViewDataSource>` to your interface, you're basically saying "I can act as a data source for a picker view and I'm ready for any picker that wants to call the methods that are declared in the protocol".

Comment: Well said. (since I have to reach 15 characters, are you the guy behind the app store sales app?)

Comment: If you're referring to [AppSales](https://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile), yes. :)

Comment: Yep, was referring to that. By the way, when the reports are delayed, the portal shows a message which seems to cause problems when downloading.

Comment: Ok. I conform to the protocol, that means I have to define some specific methods as stated in the protocol. I don't have to declare them because those are declared in the protocol declaration somewhere else. I presume the picker instance is calling those methods to get data because it knows the controller is following the protocol.

But then let's say I have 2 pickers on the same view. Do they use the same methods from the protocol? do I have to implement some way of knowing what picker is calling the method and act accordingly?

BTW I use newsRack!

Comment: You could assign different data sources for different pickers. The picker doesn't just call your controller because it conforms to the protocol, it calls the data source that you assigned somewhere (which must conform to the protocol). If you assign the same controller as the data source for multiple pickers, they will call the same method on the same object and you have to differentiate them somehow in your code (that's why all the data source methods have the picker that's calling them as a parameter).

Comment: @omz - How did you do that button on the UIPickerView, in the Graphs view in the iPod UI?

Comment: @Moshe Plain old `UIButton` with `UIButtonStyleCustom` and a background image that fakes the toolbar button style...

Comment: @omz - Oh, right. I actually looked at the source code. Thanks!